# Disabling a cipher / cipher suite in postfix / TLS for specific recipient

Tags: ssl, postfix, openssl

We use Postfix 2.9.4 and OpenSSL 0.9.8j-fips 07 Jan 2009 (SLES11 SP4).

We get this error message while sending mail to a specific recipient:

```
error:1408D13A:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_KEY_EXCHANGE:unable to find ecdh parameters:s3_clnt.c:1336
```

Reading the code in s3_clnt.c for our OpenSSL version it says in a comment

> For now we only support named (not generic) curve and the ECParameters
>   in this case is just three bytes.

Analyzing the code this is either not a named curve type or the parameter is out of range.

My question is: How do I teach our SMTP client (or else the receiving server) to omit this cipher/cipher suite or parameter set?

Answer (score 3):

**TLS Policy Per Domain**

You can use the [Postfix TLS Policy Map](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html) to create a list of domains and what TLS policies apply to them.

You can also change your global `smtp` and `smtpd` options in postfix to limit what ciphers may or must be used.

Another option in this case would be to specify what ciphers to use as seen in [TLS Forward Secrecy in Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/FORWARD_SECRECY_README.html)  and perhaqps just use strong.

```
    smtpd_tls_eecdh_grade = strong | ultra
```

Here is an example `/etc/postfix/tls_policy`

```
.google.com     secure match=.google.com:.gmail.com protocols=TLSv1 ciphers=high
.paypal.com     secure match=.paypal.com protocols=TLSv1 ciphers=high
.example.tld    ciphers=medium
.blizzard.com   may
```

Then create the map with:

```
postmap tls_policy
```

In `/etc/postfix/main.cf` you would need:

```
smtp_tls_policy_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/tls_policy
```

In `/etc/postfix/main.cf` you might try excluding ciphers with `smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers` and `smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers` and/or set `smtpd_tls_eecdh_grade = strong`

If adjusting the cipher exclusions or setting a tls_policy does not help, then you may want to consider updating openssl and postfix.

Comment: Yes, an example for individual configuration for only this reciepient would be useful.

Comment: I already experimented with those parameters. tls_policy is a known mechanism to me. What I did not find is how to exclude discrete ciphers (e.g. ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA or all ECDH) from the list of allowd ciphers for a specific recipient. It only doesn't work for this one.

Comment: Upgrading openssl is not an option, because this is a maintained distribution. Upgrading the distribution would be an option, but not very soon...

Answer (score 2):

Solution for defining a specific cipher list for only one recipient:

master.cf: `smtp2 unix - - n - - smtp -o tls_high_cipherlist=!ECDH:...(some more)`

transport_map: `<domain> smtp2:<domain>` (second domain omittable?)

tls_policy_map: `<domain> verify match=hostname ciphers=high`

This omitts the problematic ECDH algorithms and worked in this szenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [postfix transport map](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) to route mail for specific destinations via another service defined in `master.cf`. There you should be able to use the usual postfix configuration options for TLS to enable/disable ciphers.

Comment: Could you give an example for this specific service (how to define in transport map and master.cf), please?

Comment: Hi, I found it out myself ;-)

Comment: master.cf: smtp2 unix - - n - - smtp -o tls_high_cipherlist=!ECDH:...<br>    
transport_map: <domain>  smtp2:<domain>  # (second domain omittable?) <br>
tls_policy_map: <domain> verify match=hostname ciphers=high

Comment: I think the other two answers have all needed details. I currently do not have such an setup, so i would need to test more before giving a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to solve this (instead of introducing a new master.cf entry for smtp) is to use tls_policy map and set

```
tls_policy:  <domain>    verify hostname=<hostname> exclude=kECDH
```

That's it.

If you do not have tls_policy (in an older version of postfix) you might use the parameter

```
-o smtp_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers=kECDH
```

in the master.cf entry for this domain.

Thanks to all contributors who led me the right way to find this out ;-)